# Symfony 2 Radio Button Boolean Issue?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

ok, I am running with symfony 2.7.8. I have a User Abstract form which I added an 'active' state option which seems to work, as in it aloows me to set the user active/non-active if I wish.

However, when the user is set to Non-Active (0) it does not check that radio option. It will default to checked if the user is Active (1). Am I just doing something wrong or what?

Active 'Add' section

```
  $ActiveState = [0 => 'Non-Active', 1 => 'Active'];

  ->add('active', 'choice', [
                            'label' => 'Active State',
                            'multiple' => false,
                            'choices' => $ActiveState, 
                            'expanded' => true,
                            'label_attr' => ['class' =>'Active']
                            ])
```

And this is how I build the form for loading a user

```
   $User = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('XXXXBundle:Users')
                    ->find($id); <- If i passed in url e.g. /user/ID-HERE

   $EditUser = $this->createForm(new UserType(),$User,[
                                'action' => $this->generateUrl('UserUpdate',['id' => $id]),
                                'method' => 'PUT'
                                ]);
```

When I select either of the Radio buttons it will update that user, but only have an Active User pre-checked?

So what am I doing wrong?

All help most welcome, ps. if someone wants me to post all of the controller function or the User Form, then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What type is set for this field in property mapping?

Comment: @Max P. - Do you mean in the ORM? I use .yml files and its set to boolean - I was thinking of trying it with just an integer, to see if its a problem with that but I was thinking it was more likely to be with the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with boolean property (false-0 don't work, true-1 work). I've add view transformer for this form element to make it work properly.
After `->add(...)`

```
$builder->get('active')->addViewTransformer(new \Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer(
    function ($original) {
        return $original ? 1 : 0;
    },
    function ($submitted) {
        return $submitted ? true : false;
    }
));
```

Comment: Dam, worked without any issues :) - So do you think this is a bug? With Symfony or with doctrine? I just cant see why they could get a Boolean element wrong? - Any way thanks mate!

Comment: Oh, I don't know. May be it is a feature :)